# libodbc makefile for a 64 bits processor

Tags: c++, sql, 64-bit

I am facing the issue of installing libodbc for a 64 bits processor. 
A win32 install documentation is already available but it is not applicable when compiling with a x64 platform. The compiler in this case complains since it cannot find the file "config.h". I suppose this can be produced with a nmake but the procedure is not clear for x64.
Did anyone already faced this issue and managed to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use sqlExe. It is a command line based utility that uses ODBC to connect to any database.

It is open source and the code is available at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlexe/

You could compile it for your 64 bit system.